# In django , Are there controllers like in php?

Tags: php, python, django

This is a follow up question to [How can I run a django management command by cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989549/how-can-i-run-a-django-management-command-by-cron-job). I'm trying to get a better understanding of the way to organize code, having come from php MVC frameworks.

In php ( lets say codeigniter ) , A URL will activate a specific controller.

The first answer to the above question states:

```
One option is, you can create a URL endpoint, and the corresponding view would call the management command.
```

Without much python/django knowledge, it just seems surprising to me that so you have to get a  view involved in running an abritrary app or  a controller-like piece of code where no output is needed. Is this really the only way to do this in Django? If so why is it structured this way?

Comment: Mostly it is differing nomenclature, not responsibility.  A framework like Code Igniter is referred to as MVC (Model View Controller) whereas Django is ofter referred to as a MTV (Model Template View) where they are in the same order, meaning Template is analogous to View and View is analogous to Controller.

Comment: This is not the only way to do that, it is just another way of doing it which i will not suggest. There are some apps to do that in django to run schedule jobs e.g. [Celery] (http://www.celeryproject.org/)

Comment: Thanks guys - much appreciated. But why is it called a view? I can easily unserstand why a view is called view in codeigniter for example ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing names with actual things. A view in Django is a piece of Python code that takes a request and returns a response - in other words, exactly what some frameworks would call a controller. What CodeIgniter would call a view, Django calls a template.

Comment: That helps, Thank you Daniel. As I asked above could I also ask you why a django "controller" is called a view? what is being viewed? Best Regards, - Bill

Comment: You should instead ask why a MVC "view" is called that. In every other domain apart from MVC, an HTML file with placeholders for data is called a "template", which is what Django calls it. But see [the FAQ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names) for the Django designers' explanation.