# Collect & Store Data From API using requests in python to SQLite database

Tags: python, json, django, sqlite, request

I am new to python and django. But I am trying to set up an app in my project which collects odds data from an API then parses out what I need from the json, and then saves it to a table in an SQLite database.

So far I have the following, which gives me the data I would like to collect and store. The data will need to be called and updated if changed once or twice a day to ensure it's up to date.

```
def BluebetNrlOdds():
    """Fetch and extract JSON data from Bluebet Australia"""
    import requests
    import json

    # Bluebet Rugby League Odds API.
    link = 'https:/xxxxxxxxxx.com.au/json/reply/MasterCategoryRequest?EventTypeID=102&WithLevelledMarkets' \
           '=true&WithLevelledMarkets=true '
    # Request data from link as 'str'
    nrldata = requests.get(link).text
    # convert 'str' to Json
    nrldata = json.loads(nrldata)

    # NRL ODDS DATA
    for nrl_odds in nrldata['MasterCategories'][0]['Categories'][0]['MasterEvents']:
        competition = nrl_odds['CategoryName']
        event_id = nrl_odds['MasterEventId']
        event_title = nrl_odds['MasterEventName']
        start_time = nrl_odds['MaxAdvertisedStartTime']
        home_team = nrl_odds['Markets'][0]['OutcomeName']
        home_team_win_odds = nrl_odds['Markets'][0]['Price']
        home_team_win_handicap = nrl_odds['Markets'][2]['Points']
        home_team_handicap_odds = nrl_odds['Markets'][2]['Price']
        home_team_1_12 = nrl_odds['Markets'][4]['Price']
        home_team_13 = nrl_odds['Markets'][6]['Price']
        away_team = nrl_odds['Markets'][1]['OutcomeName']
        away_team_win_odds = nrl_odds['Markets'][0]['Price']
        away_team_win_handicap = nrl_odds['Markets'][3]['Points']
        away_team_win_handicap_odds = nrl_odds['Markets'][3]['Price']
        away_team_1_12 = nrl_odds['Markets'][5]['Price']
        away_team_13 = nrl_odds['Markets'][7]['Price']

        print(competition, event_id, event_title, start_time, home_team, home_team_win_odds, home_team_win_handicap, home_team_handicap_odds, home_team_1_12, home_team_13, away_team, away_team_win_odds, away_team_win_handicap, away_team_win_handicap_odds, away_team_1_12, away_team_13)
```

when you run that code it prints

```
NRL Telstra Premiership 1047531 Penrith Panthers v Parramatta Eels 2022-09-09T09:55:00.0000000Z Penrith Panthers 1.4 -7.5 1.95 2.85 2.58 Parramatta Eels 1.4 7.5 1.85 3.8 7.6
NRL Telstra Premiership 1047539 Melbourne Storm v Canberra Raiders 2022-09-10T07:40:00.0000000Z Melbourne Storm 1.4 -8.5 2.0 3.05 2.52 Canberra Raiders 1.4 8.5 1.8 3.85 7.9
NRL Telstra Premiership 1047538 Cronulla-Sutherland Sharks v North Queensland Cowboys 2022-09-10T09:50:00.0000000Z Cronulla-Sutherland Sharks 1.7 -2.5 1.9 3.1 3.45 North Queensland Cowboys 1.7 2.5 1.9 3.35 5.2
NRL Telstra Premiership 1047530 Sydney Roosters v South Sydney Rabbitohs 2022-09-11T06:05:00.0000000Z Sydney Roosters 1.6 -4.5 1.95 2.95 3.15 South Sydney Rabbitohs 1.6 4.5 1.85 3.6 5.8
```

I now need to save that data into SQlite database.

So far i have a seperate database.py file which has the following code in it

```
import sqlite3

# connect to database
connection = sqlite3.connect('puntsportsau')

# create cursor
c = connection.cursor()

c.execute("""SELECT TABLE bluebet_au_rugby_league_odds
(
    competition        text,
    event_id                integer
        constraint bluebet_au_rugby_league_odds_pk
            primary key,
    event_title             text,
    start_time              integer,
    home_team               text,
    home_team_win_odds      integer,
    home_team_handicap      integer,
    home_team_handicap_odds integer,
    home_team_1_12          integer,
    home_team_13            integer,
    away_team               integer,
    away_team_win_odds      integer,
    away_team_handicap      integer,
    away_team_handicap_odds integer,
    away_team_13            integer
, away_team_1_12 integer)

;""")

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

In the models.py file for the package I have the following

```
# Rugby League Odds

class BluebetNrlOdds(models.Model):
      competition = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      event_id = models.IntegerField
      event_title = models.TextField(max_length=250)
      start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      home_team = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      home_team_win_odds = models.IntegerField
      home_team_handicap = models.IntegerField
      home_team_handicap_odds = models.IntegerField
      home_team_1_12 = models.IntegerField
      home_team_13 = models.IntegerField
      away_team = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      away_team_win_odds = models.IntegerField
      away_team_handicap = models.IntegerField
      away_team_handicap_odds = models.IntegerField
      away_team_1_12 = models.IntegerField
      away_team_13 = models.IntegerField

      class Meta:
          verbose_name = 'Bluebet NRL Odds'
          verbose_name_plural = 'Bluebet NRL Odds'

     def __str__(self):
          return self.name
```

I am stuck with how I can get the data collected and parsed from the requests to save it to the SQlite database table. I need to do it once or twice a day.

Can anyone give me some direction on what I need to do or show me an example that I can work with to figure it out?

I hope that's enough detail, let me know if you need anything further to assist.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of Python and Django;

You can run Django commands with a corn job to build a complete use case.

- [HOWTO create a custom command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) call `BluebetNrlOdds` in the `handle` function and retrieve the data and save it using the model `BluebetNrlOdds`. You can also take a look at [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create).
- [HOWTO run a Django command in a cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989549/how-can-i-run-a-django-management-command-by-cron-job)

Quick notes:

In Python, the function name should follow the PEP-8 guide. You can read more about [PEP-8 style-guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.
> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility.

Drop the use of `database.py.` A Django project can handle the cursor connection using Django's [settings.DATABASES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases)

I'd advise you to go through [building your first Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/), which will guide you on how to quickly start a Django project and the concepts behind using `manag.py` `settings.py` and so on